# Compose functions with map

Tags: python

I'm using two map calls to transform a string of `'0'`s and `'1'`s into a sequence of booleans:

```py
>>> a, b = '10'
>>> a, b = map(int, (a, b))
>>> a, b = map(bool, (a, b))
>>> a, b
(True, False)
```

How to do that with only one `map`?

Comment: Have you tried `map(lambda x: bool(int(x)), (a, b))`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python doesn't have a function composition operator, so there's not a built-in way to do that. In this specific case, the easiest way to reduce the `map` call to one line is with a lambda:

```
a, b = map(lambda x: bool(int(x)), (a, b))
```

You could write a more general [`compose` function](https://mathieularose.com/function-composition-in-python/) easily enough, and use that instead:

```
def compose(*fns):
    return reduce(lambda f, g: lambda x: f(g(x)), fns, lambda x: x)

a, b = map(compose(bool, int), (a, b))
```

But to be honest, the latter method seems like overkill here.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the job done in one line of code by using a list comprehension instead of `map()` like this:

```py
>>> mask = '100110110'
>>> bools = [bool(int(letter)) for letter in mask]
>>> bools
[True, False, False, True, True, False, True, True, False]
```

Have a look at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map) to figure out the differences between using a list comprehension and `map`.